# Scale an embedded Twitch video to 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitch, twitch-api

I use the following code to embed a Twitch stream on an HTML page which uses TailwindCSS:

```
<section aria-labelledby="Live-Stream Video">
  <!-- Add a placeholder for the Twitch embed -->
  <div id="twitch-embed" phx-update="ignore"></div>

    <!-- Load the Twitch embed script -->
    <script src="https://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>

    <!-- Create a Twitch.Player object. This will render within the placeholder div -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Twitch.Player("twitch-embed", {
        channel: "example",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        autoplay: "true"
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</section>
```

The result:

[image]

The video doesn't use the full possible width of that  (within the TailwindCSS layout). I don't know how width that  is. How can I tell the Twitch.Player to use what ever space is there within the boundaries of the black area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just style the resulting container and iframe with css:

```css
#twitch-embed {
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 56.25%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#twitch-embed iframe {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `px` instead of `%` and try the parameter `allowfullscreen=true`

Comment: px in stead of % changes the width of the black background but not of the actual video. `allowfullscreen=true` doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use fixed values like `"720"` etc... Like this:

```js
new Twitch.Player("twitch-embed", {
  channel: "example",
  width: "1280",
  height: "720",
  autoplay: "true"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v1.js"></script>
<section aria-labelledby="Live-Stream Video">
  <div id="twitch-embed" phx-update="ignore"></div>
</section>
```

---

#### [Check it in action on Codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/rNjYqgG?editors=1010)

---

- Documentation: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed/video-and-clips/

---

Comment: This takes over all the screen. I only want it to get the max within it's <div>.

Comment: @wintermeyer Then set the `height` and `width` equal to the `height` and `width` of the `div`.